# How To Cause DmlException - Delete

Tags: unit-test, permissions, dml, dmlexception

I thought I would be able to take a `User` who does not have `delete` privileges on an object, delete records from that object, and get a `DmlException`. No dice. Below are the `Case` permissions for the `Standard User` profile:

[image: Read,Create,Edit]

However the following test fails:

```
static testMethod void testDmlException_Delete()
{
    List<Case> records = SObjectFactory.create(Case.sObjectType, RECORD_COUNT);
    User standardUser = new User(ProfileId = STANDARD_USER_PROFILE.Id);
    DmlException expectedException;
    system.runAs(standardUser)
    {
        try
        {
            delete records;
        }
        catch (DmlException dmx)
        {
            expectedException = dmx;
        }
    }
    //system.assertEquals(RECORD_COUNT, [SELECT count() FROM Case]);
    //system.assertNotEquals(null, expectedException);
}
```

Both of the above assertions fail when uncommented. How can a `User` whose `Profile` does not have `delete` permission manage to delete a record? Shouldn't this throw a `DmlException`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_tools_runas.htm):

> The runAs method doesn’t enforce user permissions or field-level
>   permissions, only record sharing.

Apex code runs in system context so even though the user does not have delete permissions since the delete is done via apex it is allowed.

You could instead delete the records twice, and the second deletion will cause an error:

```
static testMethod void testDmlException_Delete()
{
    List<Case> records = SObjectFactory.create(Case.sObjectType, RECORD_COUNT);
    delete records;

    DmlException expectedException;
    Test.startTest();
        try { delete records; }
        catch (DmlException dmx) { expectedException = dmx; }
    Test.stopTest();

    system.assertEquals(RECORD_COUNT, [SELECT count() FROM Case]);
    system.assertNotEquals(null, expectedException);
}
```

Comment: That is helpful for answering why my methodology does not work, but does leave unresolved the question of how to throw such an exception.

Comment: You could cause it buy using a flag to let the method know to delete the record and then attempt to delete it again? Not pretty but works. Sure Crop or sfdcfox will have a better solution

Comment: Deleting records without an `Id` causes a `TypeException`. I will play around with the double-delete idea though. Thanks!

Comment: I had a feeling I'd come up in this conversation.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I'd go with a double-delete myself. I just tested this, and it seems to be the only way to do it.

Comment: Yep double delete does cause the exception I was looking for. @Eric, if you add that to your answer, I will accept it.

Comment: done............